# Cleanly handling normal errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I use this pattern all over the place to grab data from the database and display a view:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        RequestViewModel model;
        model = this.ClientRepository.GetRequest(id);

        return View("~/Views/Requests/Index.aspx", model);
    }
```

If the repository returns null, which is the case if the record does not exist, then my page craps out and throws an error because the model is null.

I’d like to show a friendly “the requested record cannot be found” message instead of the yellow page of death or a generic “an error occurred” page.

What’s the recommended pattern to handle “normal” errors as opposed to unhandled exceptions?

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an action filter:

```
public class NullModelCheckerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (viewResult != null && viewResult.ViewData.Model == null)
        {
            // If the action selected a view to render and passed a null model
            // render the NotFound.aspx view
            var result = new ViewResult();
            result.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/NotFound.aspx";
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

And then decorate your base controller (that all your controllers derive from) with this attribute:

```
[NullModelChecker]
public class BaseController: Controller
{ }
```

This way your current code stays untouched.

--
UPDATE:

In ASP.NET MVC 3 you could register your [action filter globally](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html) without even decorating your base controller with it. Simply add the following to your `Application_Start` in `Global.asax`:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new NullModelCheckerAttribute());
```

Comment: This works for me. Any suggestion for a more specific error message for some pages?

Comment: @rboarman, yes inside your action filter you could use `filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")` and `filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")` to know exactly which controller action passed a `null` model to the view and based on this information customize the error message. You could also make your `NotFound` view strongly typed to a view model containing this information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET MVC. I'm familiar though with Spring MVC.

Why can't you just put a simple if-else condition? Like this one:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    RequestViewModel model;
    model = this.ClientRepository.GetRequest(id);

    if (model == null) {
        return View("~/Views/Requests/FriendlyError.aspx");
    }

    return View("~/Views/Requests/Index.aspx", model);
}
```

Comment: That's not a good suggestion because if you have many actions you would be writing many repetitive code.

Comment: I thought he only had a few of these. But anyway since I have zero familiarity with ASP.NET and he's asking for the general pattern, I agree with your answer. I think I provided a simplistic solution. If this is Spring MVC, the equivalent of your suggestion would probably be an interceptor.

Comment: Darin is correct. I probably have 50 or more metods that need the same logic.